# Drag a rectangle over image in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlabel

I guess there are lots of ways to achieve this. I have an application in which a video stream is shown over a custom QWidget that I have subclasses from QLabel, and painting frames using QPainter. Given that, is it possible to let the user to drag a rectangle over the image and retrieve the coordinates? The requirement is that the rectangle must be visible during the dragging.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How does the user select the rectangle? Is the rectangle "plain"? If so, it is totally possible

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [QRubberBand](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrubberband.html). It allows you to place such a rect on top of e.g. a QLabel. The documentation also contains an example how to move and resize the rubberband using the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

the `QGraphicsView` has the `void setRubberBandSelectionMode ( Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode )` but i dont know if the `QLabel` has some similar feature ...

maybe you have to draw your own rectangle while the user drags the rectangle and catch it on mouserelease

soo long zai

Answer (score 1):

In you widget you could track mouse pressed and released events and track where on the widget the corners of the selection rect are. For drawing the rectangle, I'd take a look at `QStyle::drawFocusRect`. I think the intent of that is to draw a rect you'd be able to see regardless of what's behind it.

Or perhaps try this:

```
QStylePainter painter(this);
QStyleOptionFocusRect option;
option.initFrom(this);
option.backgroundColor = palette().color(QPalette::Background);
painter.drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_FrameFocusRect, option);
```